# Repeated values for errno in man page

Tags: c, man

I'm looking at the man page for the libc function `execve` under Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm trying to handle errors as described by the man page:

```
RETURN VALUE
On success, execve() does not return, on error -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.
```

So I check below on the ERROR section and I see:

```
ERRORS
   ...
   EACCES Search permission is denied on a component of the path prefix of filename or the name of a script interpreter.  (See also path_resolution(7).)

   EACCES The file or a script interpreter is not a regular file.

   EACCES Execute permission is denied for the file or a script or ELF interpreter.

   EACCES The filesystem is mounted noexec.
   ....
```

Does this mean that `EACCES` could be *any* of these things? Or less likely *all* of them?

How can I tell them apart when handling errors from a switch statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that EACCES could be any of these things? Or less
>   likely all of them?

Any. As for "all", if there's a path traversal error, how would code even be able to try other things such as the "is it a regular file" if the code lacks permission to traverse to the file? Also returning multiple errors is not really a thing C does by default (unless you wrote some struct that contains a list of errors and then a pointer to that struct is somehow gotten back to the caller who then needs to...and that's not how most system calls are written.)

> How can I tell them apart when handling errors from a switch
>   statement?

`strerror(errno)` or the nifty `err(3)` which doubtless in turn calls `strerror` is pretty much the most you'll get:

```
$ cat sirexecsalot.c
#include <err.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
extern char **environ;
extern int errno;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret;
    errno = 0;
    if ((ret = execve("/var/tmp/exectest/hullo", ++argv, environ)) == -1)
        err(1, "nope (strerr=%s)", strerror(errno));
}

$ make sirexecsalot
cc     sirexecsalot.c   -o sirexecsalot
$ cat /var/tmp/exectest/hullo
#!/usr/bin/env expect
puts hi

$ ./sirexecsalot
hi
$ mv /var/tmp/exectest/hullo /var/tmp/exectest/foo
$ mkdir /var/tmp/exectest/hullo
$ ./sirexecsalot              
sirexecsalot: nope (strerr=Permission denied): Permission denied
$ chmod 000 /var/tmp/exectest 
$ ./sirexecsalot             
sirexecsalot: nope (strerr=Permission denied): Permission denied
$
```

Comment: Great thanks! I had no idea about `strerror` or `err`, definitely useful functions!

Comment: There is also `perror()`